# Analytic functions equal to all orders in a point are equal on the open interval

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ be open. To make everything clear, my definition of analytic function here is:

> A function $\psi : A\to \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^\infty$ is said to be analytic if for each $a\in A$ there is a neighborhood $V_a\subset A$ such that
>
> $$\psi(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\psi^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n, \quad \forall x\in V_a.$$

Now let $I$ be an open interval and $f,g:I\to \mathbb{R}$ analytic functions. I'm trying to show that If there is $a\in I$ such that $f(a)=g(a)$ and $f^{(n)}(a)=g^{(n)}(a)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $f=g$.

Since $f,g$ are analytic, there is a neighborhood $V_a$ of $a$ where we can write those series representations for $f$ and $g$. Obviously $f=g$ when both restricted to $V_a$.

We can then consider all the other points of $V_a$. Since $f=g$ on each of then and $f^{(n)}=g^{(n)}$ on each of then, for each such point there will be a new neighborhood and we can repeat this process there.

Intuition tells that with this we can cover the interval with those neighborhoods and on each of then the functions are equal so they will be equal over the whole interval.

Now, although intuitively it is clear, I'm not getting how to properly write this in a rigorous way.

My try was the following: pick $b\in I$ and suppose that $b < a$ (the case $a < b$ is analogous). Since $I$ is open, there's one interval around $b$, say $(b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$, contained in $I$. Since $f,g$ are analytic there is a neighborhood of $a$ on which they are equal.

Now here comes the problem, what I should intuitively do is to pick one of the leftmost points in $V_a$ and construct a new neighborhood and continue this inductively until intercpeting the interval $(b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$.

Is my idea correct? If so, how can I finish this proof and write my idea in a rigorous way? If not, how can I prove this result properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Let
$$
S=\{t\in I : f^{(n)}(t)=g^{(n)}(t)\,\,\text{for all $n\in\mathbb N$}\}.
$$
It suffices to show that $S$ is open and closed in $I$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\phi = f-g$. Then $\phi$ is analytic on $I$.

Let $Z = \{ x | \phi^{(n)}(x) = 0 \ \forall n\}$.

Since the $\phi^{(n)}$ are continuous we see that $Z$ is closed.

Since $\phi$ is analytic, we see that $Z$ is open, hence $Z$ is connected.